# convert HH::SS to milliseconds of today's date in javascript

Tags: javascript, react-native, date, datetime, time

Hi i have a time format like this

```
"6:00 AM"
```

i want to convert it to milliseconds of Today in UTC so the result will be like this in javascript :

```
1655272809963
```

which corresponds to : `Wed Jun 15 2022 06:00:09`

any ideas ? thank you

Comment: I can't understand how does 1655272809963 corresponds to Wed Jun 15 2022 06:00:09? What am I missing?

Comment: https://currentmillis.com/ use this website to convert

Comment: `new Date().setUTCHours(6,0,0,0)` (currently 1655272800000).